# Received email header spf fail

Tags: email, office365, spf, email-headers

I'm troubleshooting an issue involving duplication of emails sent from an SSRS server via office 365 to customers. During investigation I looked at the email headers from duplicated emails and found that they all indicate the following:

received-spf: Fail (protection.outlook.com: domain of myDomain.com does not designate XX.XXX.XXX.XX as permitted sender) receiver=protection.outlook.com; client-ip=XX.XXX.XXX.XX; helo=;

What would be the effect (if any) on emails from myDomain.com (which is our office365 domain name) to various customers considering the above spf Fail message? I do not recognize the ip address however the domain name and hostname are correct.

Comment: Sounds like your SPF record needs to `include` the SPF record from office365.

Comment: Love how this gets voted down with no explanation, really useful.

Comment: To be fair, it's not appropriate for Stack Overflow since it's not a programming question.

Comment: happy to repost it on ServerFault if you think thats more appropriate

Comment: Two of the close votes are already suggesting that, so it will probably get moved there eventually. Regardless, what I suggested is likely the answer anyway.

Comment: I cannot view the close votes suggesting that so thats not helpful for me

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Answer (score 1):

The effect would depend on whether you have set DMARC record for your domain or not. If YES then whether you are signing your outgoing mails with DKIM or not. If your mails fails the SPF check at least they should pass the DKIM verification.